# web2py datetime picker configuration

Tags: jquery, python, web2py

I'm using default web2py datetime picker in SQLFORM:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
                       Field(
                             'date',
                             'datetime',
                             [...]
                             ),
                       [...]
                       )
```

Widget which I get with this:

[image: datatime picker]

It looks pretty OK, but I want to have time always with `00` minutes (like 1:00, 2:00 and so one). Is there some way to configure it to prevent user selecting minutes number other than `00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the default datetime picker has that option. Instead, you might be better off defining a standard string field type and using an alternative datetime picker that includes the functionality you need.